# How to play partial mp4 file in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, nio, android-videoview

i am stuck in a weird situation, as i am developing an android app which decrypts video at run time and plays it. Decryption process is already optimized and i am using RC4 algorithm and nio channel for copying but problem is that, it still takes about 1 min 10 secs for 250mb video and my client wants it maximum 15 secs. I am thinking about a solution in which i play my video while its getting decrypted and copy but its not happening i am getting error can't play this video.  I am using VideoView to play videos. Anybody have any idea, how to achieve this. I am setting my video uri using

```
v.setVideoURI(uri);
```

I can play video if i am playing once its decrypted.

Please help me out.

Comment: Is your Decryption algo written in C++/NDK? If its not then you can't say "Decryption process is already optimized" cuz u r far away from optimization at all. As for your method - Im afraid it wont play partially available mp4 and its about keyframes (video codec related stuff). IF i'm wrong about keyframes you will need also to append decrypted parts to a played file while it plays which is by itself aint an easy task.

Comment: No its in java but i can do same thing on my PC, i mean if i decrypt that video on my pc using the same java code, i can play the partial video on vlc and potplayer but on android i am having this issue. About performance i am already copying the data at very fast rate on sdcard. Its fast enough because a number of file manager copying data at lower speed rate. Thanks for your comment :-) but it will be helpful to me if you can suggest me about playing that partial file.

Comment: PC is much more powerfull than any Android device and such players as VLC could restore/ignore keyframes loss on the fly and its not noticable for you. Also check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721537/can-you-set-an-arbitrary-byte-offset-in-the-mp4-header-for-the-first-frame

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=play+mp4+partially&oq=play+mp4+partially - looks like I'm right, you wont be able to play partially decrypted (read downloaded) file on Android since it threats it as a corrupted media file.

Comment: Ok thanks stan! I will try to find another way but thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, willing to decrypt the entire video before to start playing exposes the user to a noticeable delay. You should consider a streaming architecture.

A typical design involves the javax.crypto.CipherInputStream class and a local http instance.
There is no class for an http server in the SDK, you have to implement your own one, otherwise look for an existing library similar to LocalSingleHttpServer.

It looks like:

```
mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
mServer.start();
path = mServer.getURL(path);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.start();
```