# Decrypt RTSP stream Before Play on video view

Tags: android, encryption, video-streaming, rtsp-client

i am trying to play Encrypted video stream(RTSP) on Android device.it need to be decrypted Before It play.How can we decrypt incoming RTP packets and give it to video view real time?

If anyone can advise me how to fix it, I will be Thankful.

Comment: what mistake to indicate if you don't show us the code?

Comment: sorry i didn't have clue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470858/how-to-play-partial-mp4-file-in-android may give you some hints.